# how to set typed, nullable reactive value from a test in vue

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I have a simple Vue component like with a typed ref value that is nullable and also has an initial value of `null`. When I want to change that value in a test, I get an error `TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')`. I can't figure out what I'm doing here wrong.

```
<template>
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>
import {TestType} from "@/components/types";
import {ref} from "vue";

const myVal = ref<TestType | null>(null)

</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

The test file:

```
describe('setting ref', () => {
  let wrapper: VueWrapper<any>

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(TestRef, {})
    wrapper.vm.myVal = {name: 'myname'} as TestType
  })

  it('should set member', () => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.myVal.value.name).toBe('myname')
  })
})
```